# Passing error messages in PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I have a login form on my website that checks submitted usernames/passwords.  If there's no match, the user is sent back to the login page and an appropriate error message is displayed.  The call for this redirect is this:

```
header("location:../login.php?error_message=$error_message");
```

This works fine, but it does look messy in the browser's address bar (especially with descriptive error messages).  Is there any way to do this automatic redirect without using the $_GET variable?  I had considered using the $_SESSION variable, but that doesn't seem like the best coding practice.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Personally I use the `$_SESSION` variable.

Comment: Using `$_SESSION` IS a good practice.

Comment: I'm relatively new to PHP and had been hesitant about using `$_SESSION`, as it resembles the easy-but-dangerous globals of other languages... but I'm happy to reassess. Thanks!

Comment: Why do you redirect at all? A redirect means an unnecessary roundtrip and therefore delay for the user. Why not simply output the login form again, if the validation fails?

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois I may not understand your question correctly, but I'm redirecting because the login-checking is happening in one file (check_login.php) and my form is in another (login.php).  When I reload the form due to user error, I need to send along a message describing that error.

Comment: @rogare: Then in check_login.php do `$msg = "bad things happened"; include "login.php";` and in login.php do something like `if (isset($msg)) echo $msg;`

Comment: @FrancoisBourgeois  I see, thanks for the explanation.  It would make for unexpected address bar contents (page showing a login form but URL saying "...check_login.php"), but that could still work.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What about having a simpler GET variable?

```
// something.php
header ("Location: foo.php?err=1");
```

And then in the page handling the errors:

```
// foo.php
$errors = array (
    1 => "Hello, world!",
    2 => "My house is on fire!"
);

$error_id = isset($_GET['err']) ? (int)$_GET['err'] : 0;
if ($error_id != 0 && in_array($error_id, $errors)) {
    echo $errors[$error_id];
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Great, and thanks for including the short forms for the array and if statement—those will be handy!

Comment: in_array($error_id, $errors) should be array_key_exists($error_id, $errors)

Answer (score 1):

If you don't wish to use sessions, you could use error codes instead:

```
header('Location: ../login.php?error=' . urlencode($error_code));
```

Then, inside `login.php`:

```
if (isset($_GET['error'])) {
    switch ($_GET['error']) {
        case 123: // ...
            break;
    }
}
```

Instead of a bulky switch, you could use a lookup array for error messages instead (can be language dependent).

Btw, using relative URIs in your header redirects is not recommended, an absolute (e.g. `/login.php`) or fully qualified URI (e.g. `http://example.org/login.php`) is preferred.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer re: relative URLs.  I'd been using them so that I could easily move the site between offline and online testing, but it looks like the `/` prefix should do the trick.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For the form validation you have 3 options:

1. Use AJAX to validate - so, there will be no need to redirect at all.
2. Use redirect and session to store the error message **along** with entered data.
3. Use redirect as a part of the [POST/Redirect/GET](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7215138/285587) patterm

Personally I would implement (1) and (3) for my forms. (1) for the convenience of ordinary user and (3) for backward compatibility with paranoids like myself.

Using sessions is indeed a cleanest way for the redirec-based validations, as it will leave no POSTed page in the history under any circumstances. However, in a presence of AJAX-based validation it seems a bit overkill

Comment: Most of the answer for this question are completely valid... What gives.

Answer (score 0):

You can use session based flash messages.

Look at this example : http://mikeeverhart.net/php/session-based-flash-messages/

Answer (score -3):

Using session is a good option. You can clear session value as soon as you display error. But if you don't want to use session you can modified your url like following.

```
// login failed
header("location:../login.php?status=0");
```

I prefer to use session.