# PHP: How to prevent data from being saved twice

Tags: php

I want to prevent comment from being saved twice, so I write those code, but it won't work as my expectation.
Anyone helps me? Really appreaciated. THX

```
if( isset($_SESSION['ADDING']) ) {
    jsAlert("adding now, please wait");
}

$_SESSION['ADDING'] = 1;

saving_data();
jsAlert("finish");

unset($_SESSION['ADDING']);
```

Comment: It doesn't work, so what does it do? Why wouldn't saving_data be run twice? You are not calling it in the if statement?

Comment: read PRG http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get

Comment: I think in your jquery you need to stop form submission twice.

Comment: I find my answer in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2133964/how-to-prevent-multiple-inserts-when-submitting-a-form-in-php

anyway, thx for all helps.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
You have to run your  `saving_data();` function inside `if`

```
if( isset($_SESSION['ADDING']) ) {
    jsAlert("adding now, please wait");
   saving_data();
   $_SESSION['ADDING'] = 1;
   jsAlert("finish");
  unset($_SESSION['ADDING']);
}
```