# PHP detecting a redirect to self

Tags: php

Is it possible to detect a redirect in php, if the redirect was to itelf?

in breif; can I add a line or two of code to the top of my page to first check if the page is a redirect. If it is act on it?

**PHP Final line excuted on submit**

`header("Location: " . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);`

**HTML Form**

`<form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>?submit=true" method="POST">`

Still green with php, so learning little by little. Basically I need to control some variables if the page was redirected but only if.

Comment: Don't use `PHP_SELF` it's easily compromised.

Comment: and add an `exit` after your Location header.

Comment: @Martin: It is only a simple email form. no database and no variables are being passed through the url.

Comment: even so, PHP_SELF can still be compromised as it simply takes the URL as presented to the user, it can have all sorts of GET statements added to it

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Whatever you're doing, this probably isn't the proper way to do it.

Comment: If you want a form to execute on the same page you can just leave the `action` out, there is not use for it.

Comment: You can try to  sniff through headers with `headers_list()` function to detect if there was a `'Location: ...'` header there on current script.

Comment: The goal is simply to stop resubmission of the form on page refresh. If possible I dont want to redirect at all. But I can't figure out a simple solution. I've read its better to either use ajax or redirect.

Comment: @Beaniie http://stackoverflow.com/a/2134003/2883346

Comment: @Rai: Isn't sessions a little overkill for a simple form?

Comment: I think your comment re: sessions being overkill imparts a great amount that you don't really seem to understand programming with PHP, as in, you are not understanding the *potentials* that exist, you perhaps are only seeing what you would do rather than seeing what anyone and everyone else *might* do with your form? Sessions are very easy, fairly straight forward and relatively secure. Use them.

Comment: @Beaniie Token/session system would be the best approach to this. Someone could easily abuse your refresh prevention system by not passing the referer header.

Comment: Leave `action` out of your form and add `name="submit"` to your submit button... that way you will have your `?submit=sendOrSomething` at your url to GET later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to prevent form resubmisson on page refresh, then your solution  really, really should be to POST the form data to **another** page that saves the data and then uses a `header("Location:...)` back to the form. The user will be none the wiser and the refreshing of the form page will never cause a resubmission.

As a bonus this would also mean you would no longer need to use `PHP_SELF`. As a piece of bonus advice it's usually far better to use `"http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` as PHP_SELF can have extra data added by the browser / user which can cause you issues.

It is also worth reading up on [how to defend yourself against CSRF attacks](http://www.acunetix.com/websitesecurity/csrf-attacks/).

Comment: I don't understand your comment? If you have an issue with using another file, that's your perogative rather than the industry standard or the allowances of the code.

Comment: There is so much information on the subject an industry standard simply isn't apparent to a greenhorn. I did originally build the php script in a seperate document, however many seperate sources mention referencing `($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);`.

Comment: They are poor sources. The more popular a language (or anything) becomes, the more people who *think* they know, will use things they heard from someone else who *thinks* they know. I would very politely underline that PHP_SELF should not be used, and the same data can be used *more securely* from the code I written in my answer, Also please take a good read of the CSRF link, that stuff is an extremely potent (and relatively easy to fix) issue many good programmers fail to comprehend. Even Youtube suffered from it.@Beaniie

Comment: Understood and acknowledged, I'll read up and revise my solution testing an implementation with your answer.

Comment: If you must, must (really must), use the same page, use `isset($_POST["something_from_the_form"])` to know it was submitted.

Comment: @SparK `isset` is simply not-null so `!empty` is probably more useful in checking that it's been submitted and that it actually contains data. Typically it's best to run this on the submit button as that has a fairly static content

Answer (score 2):

Put this in your script and have a look at it's content;

```
<pre>
<?php print_r($_SERVER); ?>
</pre>
```

This way you can find out which keys contain 'what' you can get which index has the referer or not and write your If Condition

you can use the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the referer like

```
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
    $cur_p="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
    if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']==$cur_p){
        //add your code here you want to do what if current == referer
    }
}
```

but HTTP_REFERER index is not always set so you can also use javascript like

```
if(document.referrer == location.href){
    //add your code
}
```

let me know if this was help full

Comment: Sorry, but this is not an answer. This should be a comment (although I realise you don't have the rep to comment, yet)

Comment: This is Same I told you Print the Server Array variable to see all the index and find which index is having the referer url, you can get the value from that index, if no index is found or empty it means there is no referer

Comment: This is not the same, as the link references what the values are and what they mean. Also please add this further information in your comment to the answer, to make it more like an answer!

Comment: you can use the $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] to get the referer

like 
if(isset($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'])){
   $cur_p="http://".$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
   if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']==$cur_p){
      add your code here
   }
}

but HTTP_REFERER index is not always set so you can also use javascript

if (document.referrer == location.href) {
    add your code
}


let me know if this was help full

Comment: Edit your anwser and put these comment details into your answer. Makes them easier to read.